# How to prevent the execution of controller upon calling state.go in an if condition?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am trying to check for a condition in controller and redirect to a different state. But the code after calling State.go is executing as well. The problem I am dealing with is that when I refresh the page using F5, the event beforeunload fires and prompt for user to choose between 'Leave this page' and 'Stay on this page'. If I choose 'Stay on this page', it leaves the page as is and it looks good. But if I choose 'Leave this page', it tries to reload the page so I am trying to redirect to a different state upon missing some data.

```
var windowElement = angular.element($window);
      windowElement.on('beforeunload', function (event) {

          console.log('refreshing the page');
          var path = $location.path();

          if (path == '/record' || path == '/recordcreated') {
              event.preventDefault();
          }
      });

      $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {
          //Do not allow to go from record created page to record page.
          if (fromState.name == 'recordcreated' && toState.name == 'record') {
              event.preventDefault();
              $state.go('home');
          }
      });

      $scope.selectedRecord = service.GetSelectedRecord();
       //Check if null and redirect to home state
      if ($scope.selectedRecord == null)
      {
          $state.go('home', {}, { reload: true });
      }

      //Continuing to execute this line
      $scope.Balance = service.GetBalance();
```

How can I make it stop executing the above line after calling state.go ? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways to achieve this:

Add the keyword `return` to the line you wish the code to stop executing at:

```
return $state.go('home', {}, { reload: true });
```

Or, append your `if` statement with an `else` block:

```
if ($scope.selectedRecord == null) {
    $state.go('home', {}, { reload: true });
} else {
    //Continuing to execute this line
    $scope.Balance = service.GetBalance();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The return is working very neat.